# Output Linq Query Result to XML

Tags: c#, sql, linq

In the SQL Server Management studio, I can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName FOR XML RAW
```

to produce a list of XML entries for the data in my table.

How do I do it in C# using LINQ queries?

```
var itemCollection = from entry in dataContextTableName select entry for xml raw
```

doesn't work (it doesn't compile).  Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you can using LINQ, Not everything possible in SQL is possible in LINQ, you'd either have to run an SQLCommand or serialise the resulting data set to xml yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a stored procedure, return the XML as an `OUTPUT` parameter and access that through the LinqToSql DataContext.

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GenerateXML

    (
        @xmlOutput nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT
    )

AS
BEGIN

    SET @xmlOutput  = ( 
        SELECT * FROM tableName FOR XML RAW
    )

END
```

From here you'd have to drag and drop the stored procedure onto your DBML file using Server Explorer, then in code it's simply:

```
string xml = "";    
dataContext.GenerateXML(ref xml)
```

[The source on this can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950494/getting-stored-procedure-output-parameter-with-linq-and-entity-framework)

As James said, you can't do it using raw LinqToSql syntax; alternatively you could serialize the result you get from a standard Linq query (eg: `from entry in dataContextTableName select entry`) into XML in code, see [here for a good starting point](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813/en-gb).